# Friend Function can't see private member

Tags: c++, function, friend

I've tried to figure this out for an hour now and I've gotten nowhere.

I have a class with a `friend` function and `private` members but I am getting a compiler error telling me that I cannot access a `private` member using that `friend` function.

```
line 36 error: 'family* family::famPtr' is private
```

The `friend` prototype is as follows within the class body

```
friend void output(family *famPtr);
```

The private members are as such:

```
private:
    string husband;
    string wife;
    string son;
    string daughter1;
    string daughter2;
    family *famPtr;
```

And this is the function call itself within the main function for a `family` object `Simpson`.

```
output(Simpson.famPtr);
```

I'm not sure where I'm messing up here, it seems relatively simple and my textbook is getting me nowhere and none of the things I've found on here have led me in the right direction.

Comment: Is your friend function in the class `Simpson` or in `family`? Also try posting more code or the line on which the error occurred. It is very hard to debug your code without your code

Comment: This question is useless not having the context (class) of the friend function

Comment: `friend` means that `output` can access stuff, not `main`.

Comment: @chris You often answer the questions as a comment ... why not answer them with an answer?

Comment: @Ben, I don't know, it feels too short. There's no explanation behind it.

Comment: @chris seems like the perfect length! Succinct and all relevant. I often see you comment the answer followed by someone else writing the same thing. Anyway, just curious.

Comment: @Ben [**Nope!**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ben Some people just refuse to get up-votes for answering trivial questions (also do not up-vote these)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was referring to Chris's comment, and if it was an answer i feel that it would be perfect.

Comment: @DieterLücking I guess so ...

Comment: @Ben Well, _@chis_ answer might hit the point, but first OP is expected to clarity their question by means of that link I've given. I'm acting in a similar way often, I just avoid to answer unclear questions but in comments, and rather downvote and close vote them. These kind of questions are usually not helpful for future research.

Comment: You need to show the `family` class, the definition of `output()` and the code where you're calling `output()`. It's possible to guess what your issue is ( you're trying to call `output()` from a function that doesn't have visibility to `family::famPtr`) but without seeing all of the code, we can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not call the function the following way

```
output(Simpson.famPtr);
```

because relative to the scope where the function is called data member `Simpson.famPtr` is private.

It is within the function where you could use expression Simpson.famPtr.

That is it is the function itself that is the friend. It is not the scope where the function is called is the class friend.

If the class would contain a public accessor like for example

```
family * get_family() const;
```

then you can call the function like

```
output(Simpson.get_family() );
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, see [here](http://ideone.com/jdPf0G) for correct and incorrect calls of `output`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I do not know. It is not my code. For example the function can create an object of the class and set its private data member directly with the value of the parameter.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I do not understand why do you ask me about the purpose of the function?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You make your life easy _"answering questions"_ man. We've been discussing this before.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I answered the question. It is you who does not answer questions and down votes entirely correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a design flaw in your program.

Making a function that takes a `family*` as input a `friend` of the class `Simpson` does not make sense at all.

The function does not deal with `Simpson`, It deals with `family`. How will making that function a `friend` of `Simpson` help?

It's difficult for me to suggest a solution since it's not clear to me why you wanted the `friend`-ship in the first place.

Comment: @R Sahu It is entirely a wrong conclusion. The function for example can create an object of the class or call other functions that return objects of the class and this function heeds to access their data members.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, that's entirely possible. It doesn't make sense at first glance. Hence the last sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Making a function a `friend` allows it to access `private` members.  It does not allow access in all calls to the function

```
output(Simpson.famPtr);
```

Here the access to `famPtr` is not made by `output`

If you change output to

```
output(family & outer)
{
   old_output(outer.famPtr);
}
```

Then the access to `private` member `famPtr` is contained within the `friend` function

Comment: I was confused about the scope of the friendship not including main, now I get it, thanks everybody.